# Redirecting from HTTP://{site name} to HHTP://{site name}

Tags: http, web

Who knows, what is the HHTP and when does it appear?

Answer (score 1):

HHTP is not a protocol that I am aware of, if you are seeing a website redirect your from HTTP to HHTP then (assuming the HHTP version does not load) it is probably a mistake in the redirection.